# Why is there a perceived difference between a Bayesian Hyperparameter and a Machine Learning Hyperparameter?

Tags: hyperparameter

There are two seperate Wikipedia articles for the term Hyperparameter. One for Bayesian statistics and another for machine learning methods.

Why is this so? BOTH of these definitions imply that hyperparameters influence other parameters. I notice that people distinguish a lot between Bayesian hyperparameter and machine learning hyperparameters. Can anyone elaborate why?